# Modulo returns result I don't understand

Tags: java, modulo

dPaid = 143.22 and b.ppTotal = 47.74. If I simply divide the remainder is 0.
But the result of this is in JAVA (and also using MOD in excel) is 47.74.

`(Math.abs(dPaid % b.ppTotal))`

Comment: See also: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3282436)

Comment: Yea ... this is a binary floating point rounding error problem.

Comment: And ... also ... an illustration of why you shouldn't use floating point for accounting.

Comment: What should you use for accounting instead?

Comment: Actually, the result in Java is 47.739999999999995 which  demonstrates the rounding error that @StephenC was talking about.

Comment: @cjingeorgia BigDecimal or convert dollars to cents.  I would prefer BigDecimal.